# Is there a way that I can use a custom footer for a template instead of using the default footer in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

Is there a way that I can have a custom template point to a specific custom footer? 
I created a template under /enterprise/template/newtemplate/test.phtml

The template works fine but it's using the default foot.phtml located in

/enterprise/template/page/html/foot.phtml

I would like for my template test.phtml to point to a different footer.

Answer (score 1):

**For Magento 1.x**:
Put below code in `local.xml`

> app/design/frontend/{your theme}/default/layout/local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
<reference name="footer">
<block type="core/template" name="mylogic" template="mylogic/mylogic.phtml"/>
</reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

write this in your `footer.html`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mylogic') ?>
```